# LPCWSTR* returning a string with the first character incorrect

Tags: c, string, winapi

In this code I'm attempting to pass a directory name from a Common Item Dialog to the characters of a Edit control and to a structure. All-most all the characters come back correct, except the first one. The first character is always replaced by a random character or symbol. I'm still learning all the ins and outs of the Win32 API so, this doesn't make any sense to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
LPNMHDR pnmh = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
    HWND Parent = GetParent(hDialog);
    wchar_t StringBuffer[150];
    LPCWSTR String = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
    {
        StringBuffer[i] = NULL;
    }

    String = &StringBuffer;

    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        
        return FALSE;


    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {

        switch (pnmh->code)
        {
        case PSN_SETACTIVE:
            PropSheet_SetWizButtons(Parent, PSWIZB_NEXT | PSWIZB_BACK | PSWIZB_CANCEL);
            return FALSE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case IDC_PjDirBrowse:
            {
                switch (HIWORD(wParam))
                {
                    case BN_CLICKED:
                        OpenDirectory (&String);
                        if (String != NULL)
                        {
                            //Load the return folder directory into the appropriate structure and the edit control
                            Environment.ProjectPath = String;
                            SetDlgItemTextW(hDialog, IDC_EDIT1, String);
                        }
                        return FALSE;
                }
                
            }

            return FALSE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

//CoCreate Folder Open Dialog Object
    IFileDialog* pfd = NULL;
    IID OpenFileID = IID_IFileOpenDialog;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IFileOpenDialog, &pfd);
    wchar_t Buffer[150];
    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
    {
        Buffer[i] = NULL;
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {

        //flags
        DWORD dwFlags;
        hr = pfd->lpVtbl->GetOptions(pfd, &dwFlags);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pfd->lpVtbl->SetOptions(pfd, dwFlags | FOS_FORCEFILESYSTEM | FOS_PICKFOLDERS);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IShellItem* MyDoccuments;

                hr = SHGetKnownFolderItem(&FOLDERID_DocumentsLibrary, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, &IID_IShellItem, &MyDoccuments);

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pfd->lpVtbl->SetFolder(pfd, MyDoccuments);


                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        hr = pfd->lpVtbl->Show(pfd, NULL);

                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            IShellItem* psiResult;

                            hr = pfd->lpVtbl->GetResult(pfd, &psiResult);

                            // We are just going to print out the 
                                          // name of the file for sample sake.
                            LPCWSTR pszFilePath = &Buffer;
                            hr = psiResult->lpVtbl->GetDisplayName(psiResult, SIGDN_FILESYSPATH,
                                &pszFilePath);



                            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                            {
                                TaskDialog(NULL,
                                    NULL,
                                    L"CommonFileDialogApp",
                                    pszFilePath,
                                    NULL,
                                    TDCBF_OK_BUTTON,
                                    TD_INFORMATION_ICON,
                                    NULL);
                                *ReturnString = pszFilePath;
                                CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                            }
                            psiResult->lpVtbl->Release(psiResult);
                        }
                    }
                    MyDoccuments->lpVtbl->Release(MyDoccuments);
                }

            }
        }

        pfd->lpVtbl->Release(pfd);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not your issue, but you're never calling `CoTaskMemFree()` on the string that was returned to you.

Comment: Actually I am. I just accidentally omitted it. I'll add it back on here. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't free it *there* (if talking about pszFilePath) since you release the memory it sits on. free it after the OpenDirectory call once you've finished using it. But then `Environment.ProjectPath = String;` seems suspect too, you copy the pointer but not the string, depends on the code we don't see

Comment: The root problem here is to realize there's no fancy string class anywhere in sight. No hard copies. It's all just raw C pointers hidden under layers of gibberish.

Comment: I see several places where the code is assigning a `wchar_t (*)[]` (pointer to array) to a `wchar_t*` (pointer to char), which is just wrong. You don't need the `wchar_t*` at all, use the `wchar_t[]` as-is and let it *decay* into a `wchar_t*`. For instance, `String = &StringBuffer;` should be `String = StringBuffer;` or get rid of `String` and just use `StringBuffer`. Same with `pszFilePath = &Buffer;`

Comment: To summarize: The code does a `CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath)` which frees the memory before the caller can use it. That's why the caller gets a corrupted string.

Comment: @RaymondChen You are absolutely right. Duh! I can't believe I didn't realize this. So if I call CoTaskMemFree from the calling procedure and pass the pointer after I save that to a buffer, would that work?

Answer (score 0):

`LPCWSTR` is Windows gibberish aka "Hungarian notation" where the LP part means "long pointer". Essentially a pointer hidden behind a `typedef`, which is very bad practice, but it is what it is...

So this is similar to declaring a `char*` (or the 16 bit equivalent which may or may not be `wchar_t` depending on compiler) without setting it to point anywhere. That won't do - just like in basic C, you need to set the pointer to point at allocated memory. Declare an array and pass it.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings

Almost all Win API functions take a pointer to a caller-allocated buffer as well as a size, then write to the buffer and perhaps tell you how many bytes that were written through another parameter. If you pass a null pointer, you invoke undefined behavior.

Or in the rare case where the function does return an allocated string, you can't do things like `*ReturnString = pszFilePath;` ... `CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);`. Because you will then free what `ReturnString` points at. There is no string class anywhere! This is C, there are just pointers and Hungarian notation to hide them away.

Comment: Systems Hungarian notation is incredibly helpful in describing an ABI. If you're taking offense with the `L` in `LP`, the "plain" pointer aliases have been around for decades (e.g., `PCWSTR`).

Comment: *"If you pass a null pointer, you invoke undefined behavior."* - That's incorrect. Pretty much all APIs that take pointer values accept the invalid null pointer value and still exhibit well-defined behavior. Consult the documentation, and if you don't trust the documentation, observe the SAL annotations in the SDK header files.

Comment: @IInspectable I am just pointing out that this is clearly the root of all problems here. The OP seems to be thinking they have some string class objects. They don't seem to realize that they are actually using raw pointers. We needn't beat the dead horse about Hungarian notation, every argument against it was already made in the 1990s (and are still valid). It's the cause of this bug, too, like millions of bugs before it.

Comment: You are exactly right. Thanks. It makes allot of sense now. Thanks for pointing out the obvious!

Comment: I've updated the code to add the appropriate buffers, however I'm still getting the same error. Is there any other explanation for this behavior? Acording the debug output window from vs2019 the error occurs in-between the*ReturnString = pszFilePath; and &String. Somehow between the two, the value changes. This I don't understand.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the code I settled on. I added the appropriate arrays, and I completely re-wrote the code to get the path to the user's documents folder. I also ended up passing the character array one character at a time, otherwise I would end up with the first character corrupted no matter what I did. Note: This code doesn't yet account for the user entering more characters than the buffer saves. This will be handled via a MessageBox.

```
BOOL CALLBACK PrpEnvironmentVarsProc(HWND hDialog, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPNMHDR pnmh = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
    HWND Parent = GetParent(hDialog);
    HWND wProjectName = NULL;
    
    HRESULT hr;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PATH - 40; i++)
    {
        Environment.ProjectPath[i] = NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        Environment.ProjectName[i] = NULL;
    }
    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        
        return FALSE;

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        
        return FALSE;
    }

    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {

        switch (pnmh->code)
        {
        case PSN_SETACTIVE:
            PropSheet_SetWizButtons(Parent, PSWIZB_NEXT | PSWIZB_BACK | PSWIZB_CANCEL);

            //Test if the ProjectName and Directory have been set. If they have, display their contents
            if (Environment.ProjectName[0] != NULL)
            {
                SetDlgItemText(hDialog, IDC_EDIT2, &Environment.ProjectName);
            }
            if (Environment.ProjectPath[0] != NULL)
            {
                SetDlgItemText(hDialog, IDC_EDIT1, &Environment.ProjectPath);
            }
            return FALSE;

        case PSN_WIZNEXT:
            {
                //Retreive the window handle
                wProjectName = FindWindowEx(hDialog, NULL, TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT ("IDC_EDIT2"));

                //Get the text Contained within the edit control
                GetDlgItemText(hDialog, IDC_EDIT2, &Environment.ProjectPath, 40);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (HIWORD(wParam))
        {
            case BN_CLICKED:

                switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                        
                case IDC_PjDirBrowse:
                        {
                            hr = OpenDirectory(&Environment.ProjectPath);

                            if (hr == S_OK)
                            {
                                if (Environment.ProjectPath != NULL)
                                {
                                //Load the return folder directory into the appropriate structure and the edit control
                                SetDlgItemTextW(hDialog, IDC_EDIT1, Environment.ProjectPath);
                                }
                        }
                        
                        return FALSE;
                }
                return FALSE;
            }

            return FALSE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

HRESULT OpenDirectory(wchar_t *ReturnString)
{

    //CoCreate Folder Open Dialog Object
    IFileDialog *pfd = NULL;
    IID OpenFileID = IID_IFileOpenDialog;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IFileOpenDialog, &pfd);
    LPCTSTR MyDoccumentsPath;


    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        
                //flags
                DWORD dwFlags;
                hr = pfd->lpVtbl->GetOptions(pfd, &dwFlags);

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pfd->lpVtbl->SetOptions(pfd, dwFlags | FOS_FORCEFILESYSTEM | FOS_PICKFOLDERS);

                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        //Get the path to the current users Doccuments folder

                        IShellItem *MyDoccuments = NULL;
                        IKnownFolderManager *FManager = NULL;
                        IKnownFolder *Folder;
                        hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_KnownFolderManager, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IKnownFolderManager, &FManager);
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            hr = FManager->lpVtbl->GetFolder(FManager, &FOLDERID_Documents, &Folder);

                            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                            {
                                hr = Folder->lpVtbl->GetShellItem(Folder, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, &IID_IShellItem, &MyDoccuments);

                                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                                {
                                    //Set the Open Folder Dialog to open at the My Doccuments Folder
                                    hr = pfd->lpVtbl->SetFolder(pfd, MyDoccuments);


                                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                                    {
                                        hr = pfd->lpVtbl->Show(pfd, NULL);

                                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                                        {
                                            //Return the path to the directory of the Project Path
                                            IShellItem* psiResult;

                                            hr = pfd->lpVtbl->GetResult(pfd, &psiResult);

                                            
                                            LPCTSTR pszFilePath = NULL;
                                            hr = psiResult->lpVtbl->GetDisplayName(psiResult, SIGDN_FILESYSPATH,
                                                &pszFilePath);



                                            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                                            {
                                                //Return the String to the calling procedure
                                                while (*pszFilePath != NULL)
                                                {
                                                    *ReturnString = *pszFilePath;
                                                    ++pszFilePath;
                                                    ++ReturnString;
                                                }
                                                //Free the pointer and then free the Memory block Allocated by GetDisplayName
                                                pszFilePath = NULL;
                                                CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                                            }
                                            
                                            psiResult->lpVtbl->Release(&psiResult);
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            }


                        }

                        FManager->lpVtbl->Release(&FManager);
                        Folder->lpVtbl->Release(&Folder);
                        
                    }
                }

        }
    pfd->lpVtbl->Release(pfd);

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Really long lines makes your code unreadable on Stackoverflow...

Comment: `pszFilePath = NULL; CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);` is an elaborate no-op. You can have the same memory leak without wasting CPU cycles on trying to release memory behind a null pointer.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Good to know. I'll break them up next time. I'm still new at this so any help or pointers is always appreciated.

Comment: @Inspectable So, If I don't set the pointer to NULL I get an Invalid Heap Address error. Can you explain that.